# Как правильно перенаправить на другую страницу?

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте!) Как известно Internet Explorer "корявит" страницы, и некоторые просто перенаправляют пользователей на страницу для загрузки других браузеров, ссылаясь на то, что сайт не поддерживает ваш браузер. Решил и я попробовать так сделать:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body onload="brow();">
```

сам script.js:

```
function brow()
    {var br;
     br = navigator.appName; 
     if (br == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
      { window.location.href="browser.html";
       }
     else window.location.href="main.html";
    }
```

НО в итоге все равно при загрузке страницы, она загружается полностью, пользователь видит корявый дизайн, и лишь потом вылезает сообщение о том чтоб включить выполнение скриптов.

Как не допустить этого?

Спасибо.

Comment: Ну либо запускать из `<head>` (а то написали "запускать скрипт после полной загрузки тега body"['body onload="brow();"'] и удвляетесь), либо на уровне сервера (php) обрабатывать.

Comment: из <head>?? типа <head onLoad="">?? А разве может работать функция до её объявления?.. Я думал, что скрипты выполняется в первую очередь, чем загрузка содержимого страницы...

Comment: Нет, `<head>...<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">brow();</script>...</head>`

Даже если скрипты подгружаются асинхронно, обрабатываются они по порядку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего распознавать броузер на стороне сервера. И либо выдавать соответствующий контент сразу перенаправлять на другую страницу (303 заголовок)